# ansible- run first task on all servers and move to 2nd task

Tags: ansible

how to do this logic.

run first task on all 4 servers in inventory and register in ls_file
Then using 2nd task send a SINGLE mail to user with the contents of ls_file

```
   - name: check file
     shell: ls -l /var/abcd.txt
     register: ls_file




   - name: send mail to user
     mail:
       host: relay.server
       port: 25
       from: abcd@company.com
       to: manager <manager@company.com>
       subject: file availability
```

mail body should be as below.

```
       server1 - -rw-------. 1 root root 4405 Apr 20  2020 /var/abcd.txt
       server2 - -rw-------. 1 root root 4405 Apr 12  2020 /var/abcd.txt
       server3 - -rw-------. 1 root root 4405 Mar 15  2020 /var/abcd.txt
       server4 - -rw-------. 1 root root 4405 Apr 19  2020 /var/abcd.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
  - name: send mail to user
    mail:
      host: relay.server
      port: 25
      from: abcd@company.com
      to: manager <manager@company.com>
      subject: file availability
      body: |-
        {% for servervars in hostvars | dict2items | map(attribute="value") | selectattr('ls_file', 'defined') %}
          {{ servervars.inventory_hostname }} - {{ servervars.ls_file.stdout }}
        {% endfor %}
    delegate_to: localhost
    run_once: true
```

This will create a line in your mail for any server where the variable `ls_file` exists.

Some refs worth to read:

- [Jinja2 `for` control structure](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for)
- [Playbook delegation, controlling where task run](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html)
- [Ansible special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) (look for `hostvars`)
- [Playbook keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html) (look for `run_once`).

Comment: Got this error

fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ls_file'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/ls.yml': line 18, column 10, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n       - name: send mail to manager\n         ^ here\n"}

Comment: Do you have other servers in your inventory than the 4 you run the command on ? Did your run anything on localhost prior to running that task ? Editing the answer with a more secure solution anyway.

Comment: Secured the solution so that it does not fail if a particular server in inventory does not have the `ls_file` var defined.

Comment: There are only 4 servers in my inventory. Nothing ran before the task.  Is it the typo "enfor" corrected in your answer ? I noticed it and used "endfor" in the first place.  So with this the playbook gave me that error.

Comment: That typo gave an other error message and I fixed it as well. What's the result with the current version ?

Comment: When your say "nothing run before the task", I suppose you mean nothing besides the task I gave above as an example AND the previous "check file" task ? If you don't run that task with the register, the mail body will be empty (or you would get a non existent attribute error with the previous version....)

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly.. sorry that i have a small typo... Thank you for the quick help.

Comment: If this fixes your issue, please consider accepting the answer (green tick) to let others know there is a working solution.

Comment: btw, i used this logic for  command "uptime |awk '{print $3}'" in place of  ls -l.. now can i use a when condition to compare the uptime days more than 100 so only those severs will be sent in mail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229625/discussion-between-sharma-and-zeitounator).

Comment: Sure, i pinged you on the chat.

Comment: i used this logic for command "uptime |awk '{print $3}'" in place of ls -l.. now can i use a when condition to compare the uptime days more than 100 so only those severs will be sent in mail